# \htext undefined control sequence with paperandpencil.sty

Tags: packages

I'm trying to create a questionnaire using paperandpencil.sty from [QDDS](http://www.qdds.de/index.php?id=129). I've already figured out how to create a question using `\question` and an answer using `\hup`. I tried to make a yes/no answer using `\htexttwo{Yes}{No}` but I get

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.34 \htexttwo
          {Yes}{No}
```

Any ideas why this wouldn't work? I think I am doing it according to the [documentation](http://www.qdds.org/fileadmin/files/Documentation_en_paper%2Bpencil.pdf) (PDF link). I am using MiKTeX and TeXworks on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

True, the style file defines `\htextthree` ... `\htextseven`, but no `\htexttwo`. Using the definitions they provide in `paperandpencil.sty` for the above choices, the following matches for `\htexttwo`:

```
\newcommand{\htexttwo}[2]{\vspace{0.5cm}
  \begin{center}\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{3cm}p{0.001cm}}
  \centering #1&\centering #2\\&\\\centering$\Box$&\centering$\Box$ \\
  \end{tabular}\end{center}\vspace{0.5cm}}
```

The package seems old and not as user-friendly in terms of its coding. The use of a `0.001cm` end-column can be done *more better-er*. It's easy to assume that there are far better/more convenient ways of obtaining what you're after.

Either way, here's a complete minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{paperandpencil}

\newcommand{\htexttwo}[2]{\vspace{0.5cm}
  \begin{center}\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{3cm}p{0.001cm}}
  \centering #1&\centering #2\\&\\\centering$\Box$&\centering$\Box$ \\
  \end{tabular}\end{center}\vspace{0.5cm}}

\begin{document}

\question{This is a question?}

\htexttwo{A}{B}
\htextthree{A}{B}{C}
\htextfour{A}{B}{C}{D}
\htextfive{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}
\htextsix{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}
\htextseven{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Seriously? It just doesn't have `\htexttwo` defined? Thanks for your help Werner. Would you be able to recommend a better way of doing this? This package is the only thing I was able to find.

Comment: @gla3dr: Yes, `\htexttwo` is just undefined in the package. I would only be able to suggest better alternatives once I see the full extent of your usage.

Comment: This works great. Just had to fix one typo in your code (&& instead of &) causing a `! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.` error, but I'm not allowed to do a single-character edit.

Comment: Regarding my usage, I am basically just using `\hupB` and `\htext`. I essentially have some questions where the answers are a 1-5 rating, and some yes/no questions. Maybe also some open questions where there would just be a line to write on. Do you have any suggestions for that?